# error al ejecutar mi clase 'Ventana' object has no attribute 'creOne'

Tags: python, class, pygame

Sé que hay un método en Pygame para dibujar círculos, pero quiero intentar hacerlo en una clase, sin embargo me da este error al ejecutar **'Ventana' object has no attribute 'creOne'**

código - "clase Círculo", esta es mi clase "círculo" donde tengo los parámetros necesarios para dibujar mi círculo y dentro un método usando pygame.draw:

```
**class Circulo(PosGeo):
    def __init__(self, ven, colorFig, x, y, r):
        self.ven = ven
        self.colorFig = colorFig
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radio = r
       
        self.cx = x+r
        self.cy = y+r
    
    def dibujar(self):
        pg.draw.circle(self.ven, self.colorFig, (self.x, self.y), self.radio)**
```

código - principal, aquí ejecuto mi clase de círculo y donde establezco los valores que deseo:

**

```
class Ventana:
    def __init__(self, Ven_Tam= (700, 500)):
        
        pg.init()
        self.ven_tam = Ven_Tam
        self.ven = pg.display.set_caption("Linea")
        self.ven = pg.display.set_mode(self.ven_tam)
        self.ven.fill(pg.Color('#404040'))
        
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                quit()
        pg.display.flip()
    def CrearC(self):
        self.creOne = Circulo(self.ven, "white", 100, 200, 100)
    def DibOb(self):
        self.creOne.dibujar(self)#aquí es donde obtengo el error 'Ventana' object has no attribute 'creOne'
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.DibOb()
            self.check_events()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ven = Ventana()
    ven.run()
```

**

Comment: Buen día, no era necesario crear una nueva pregunta, pudiste haber traducido tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/570446/171630), te recomiendo eliminar alguna de las dos (Tal vez la otra) ya que publicar varias veces la misma pregunta es considerado `spam` y va en contra de las normas del sitio. Saludos!

Comment: Hay varias líneas donde aparece `creOne`. El mensaje de error te dice cual. ¿Cual es la línea del error?

Comment: @CandidMoe sobre **creOne** deje un comentario en la linea donde me da el error, pero para ser mas concreto es en la funcion **DibOb()**

Comment: @HeytalePazguato lo siento, no se como eliminar la pregunta, pero lo hare en cuanto pueda

Comment: Claramente has llamado a `DibOb()` antes que llamar a `CrearC`. En realidad no hay razón para este último método: puedes crear el círculo directamente en el `__init__()` , pues todos sus valores son constantes. Asi el atributo estará siempre definido.

Comment: Es recomendable siempre inicializar todos los atributos de un objeto en el `__init()__`. Ayuda a la mejor comprensión del código y evita errores dando valores por default adecuados.

Comment: @CandidMoe de ante mano gracias por contestar, lo que hice fue directamente desacerme de **DibOb()** y colocar la instruccion en **CrearC** solo por probar sin saber porque ahora si funcionaba pero no habia tomado en cuenta lo que has mencionado, "claramente has llamado a **DibOb()** antes que llamar. a **CrearC**"

Comment: @CandidMoe podria hacerle una pregunta?, solo que es mucho mas extensa

Comment: @Moy Para una mejor respuesta, formula una nueva pregunta.